# Nodejs OpenAI wrapper BadRequestError: 400 Uploaded image must be a PNG and less than 4 MB

Tags: node.js, typescript, openai-api

I'm trying to use OpenAI Dall-e 2 to edit an image of mine with the official Nodejs SDK.

But, I've a problem:

This is the code:

```js
const image = fs.createReadStream(`./dist/lab/${interaction.user.id}.png`)

const mask = fs.createReadStream(`./dist/lab/${interaction.user.id}-finish.png`)

                
const response = await openai.images.edit({
           image: image as any,
           mask: mask as any,
           prompt: prompt ?? "Modifica l'immagine in base al prompt.",
});
```

It gives me this error:

```
/root/bot-vinted/node_modules/openai/error.js:44
            return new BadRequestError(status, error, message, headers);
                   ^

BadRequestError: 400 Uploaded image must be a PNG and less than 4 MB.
    at APIError.generate (/root/bot-vinted/node_modules/openai/error.js:44:20)
    at OpenAI.makeStatusError (/root/bot-vinted/node_modules/openai/core.js:263:33)
    at OpenAI.makeRequest (/root/bot-vinted/node_modules/openai/core.js:306:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /root/bot-vinted/dist/index.js:272:34 {
  status: 400,
  headers: {
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
    'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
    'cf-ray': '8589fdebdb7b66d6-AMS',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '179',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    date: 'Tue, 20 Feb 2024 21:55:07 GMT',
    'openai-organization': 'user-elsxtplkdd9v4yiicc4opnys',
    'openai-processing-ms': '144',
    'openai-version': '2020-10-01',
    server: 'cloudflare',
    'set-cookie': '__cf_bm=pqRaPEw_XFt0bYujt3rEsjsjIgORgdTCn4N5pBb8AKg-1708466107-1.0-ASX4tWLN4a9loWpMIkGBwVT2VscAQHZdH1WHEUV+bCBsXb73a9w2NKACk3x4v5s1MREA5ACb7yZhkq3pBibBZKc=; path=/; expires=Tue, 20-Feb-24 22:25:07 GMT; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None, _cfuvid=aH9vifO2z_039zBnesQpYpvWxlt9Sq9JaBWyPx5sUIw-1708466107058-0.0-604800000; path=/; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
    'x-request-id': 'req_30d6190abd2e575e3bcaecd5070dfee4'
  },
  error: {
    code: 'invalid_image_format',
    message: 'Uploaded image must be a PNG and less than 4 MB.',
    param: null,
    type: 'invalid_request_error'
  },
  code: 'invalid_image_format',
  param: null,
  type: 'invalid_request_error'
}
```

I'm sure that the image is in PNG format and that is less than 4MB.
Someone can help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your evidence for your belief?

Comment: @user207421 what belief? If you are talking about the file, the extension is PNG and the size is 800kb

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot this without the actual files, it would help to share them so that others can try and replicate the error.

In general, I suggest you:

1. Hardcode some sample pictures and try if it works with them
2. Use a library like [image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size) to check the image type and size at runtime.

Regarding (1), this Jupyter notebook is based on the latest documentation and works for me:

```py
import os
from openai import OpenAI
from IPython.display import Image, display

my_key = "sk-XXX"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = my_key
client = OpenAI()

response = client.images.edit(
  model="dall-e-2",
  image=open("image_edit_original.png", "rb"),
  mask=open("image_edit_mask.png", "rb"),
  prompt="A sunlit indoor lounge area with a pool containing a flamingo",
  n=1,
  size="1024x1024"
)
image_url = response.data[0].url

display(Image(url=image_url))
```

Playing around with this, it seems that you need to be careful to actually provider `.png` images (and e.g. not just provide renamed files). There are also some restrictions on transparency (but this is another error code).

The pictures in the sample above were downloaded from the [sample data](https://github.com/betalgo/openai/tree/master/OpenAI.Playground/SampleData) mentioned [here](https://community.openai.com/t/how-can-i-provide-a-rgba-png-file-to-openai-php-library/22604/3).